# winsock2 socket connection works within local pc, but not from remote pcs

Tags: c, windows, sockets, networking, winsock2

I'm trying to learn low level networking in c, and have gotten as far as making TCP client and server programs that make, bind, connect, accept, etc. sockets using winsock.

They work just fine, and my simple chat console works as intended when both programs are running on the same machine, but connecting from a client on another pc over my local network, or another network, fails to communicate over the socket connection.

Here are my server:

```
#include "sockets.h"

int main(){

    // SETUP AND BIND SERVER SOCKET

    SOCKET server_socket = socket_setup();
    SOCKADDR_IN address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.86.179"); //using LAN IP, not local (127.0.0.1)
    address.sin_port = htons(6502);

    if(bind(server_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&address, sizeof(address)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        WSA_ERR("Socket Bind Error");

    if(listen(server_socket, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        WSA_ERR("Listening Error");

    SOCKET accept_socket = SOCKET_ERROR;
    do{
        accept_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);
    }
    while(accept_socket == SOCKET_ERROR);

    // SEND AND RECEIVE BYTES

    char sendmsg[100] = "Hello Client";
    char recvmsg[100] = "";

    int bytes_sent = send(accept_socket, sendmsg, strlen(sendmsg), 0);
    if(bytes_sent == SOCKET_ERROR){
        WSA_ERR("Send Error");
    }else{
        printf("Send OK\n");
        printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", bytes_sent);
        printf("%s\n", sendmsg);
    }

    int bytes_rcvd = blocking_recv(accept_socket, recvmsg);
    if(bytes_rcvd == SOCKET_ERROR){
        WSA_ERR("Recv Error");
    }else{
        printf("Recv OK\n");
        printf("Bytes Rcvd: %ld\n", bytes_rcvd);
        printf("%s\n", recvmsg);
    }

    chat_loop(recvmsg, sendmsg, accept_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

and client:

```
#include "sockets.h"

int main(){

    // SETUP AND CONNECT CLIENT SOCKET

    SOCKET client_socket = socket_setup();
    SOCKADDR_IN address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    printf("Enter IP address:\n");
    char ip[15];
    gets_s(ip, 15);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    address.sin_port = htons(6502);

    if(connect(client_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&address, sizeof(address)) == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK){
        WSA_ERR("Connection Error");
    }

    // SEND AND RECIEVE BYTES

    char sendmsg[100] = "Hello Server";
    char recvmsg[100] = "";

    int bytes_rcvd = blocking_recv(client_socket, recvmsg);
    if(bytes_rcvd == SOCKET_ERROR){
        WSA_ERR("Recv Error"); //<-- WSAGetLastError() from inside macro gives error 10057 here
    }else{
        printf("Recv OK\n");
        printf("Bytes Rcvd: %ld\n", bytes_rcvd);
        printf("%s\n", recvmsg);
    }

    int bytes_sent = send(client_socket, sendmsg, strlen(sendmsg), 0);
    if(bytes_sent == SOCKET_ERROR){
        WSA_ERR("Send Error");
    }else{
        printf("Send OK\n");
        printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", bytes_sent);
        printf("%s\n", sendmsg);
    }

    chat_loop(recvmsg, sendmsg, client_socket);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This function is part of "sockets.h":

```
int blocking_recv(SOCKET sock, char buf[]){
    int result = 0;
    do{
        result = recv(sock, buf, 100, 0);
    }while(result == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK);
    return result;
}
```

I can elaborate on excluded code and macros if needed, but I think the problem must be in here somewhere since everything works fine except for the actual connections.

I've already disabled all firewalls, forwarded port, etc.
I'm using non-blocking sockets.

Comment: `ip` isn't big enough.

Comment: @dbush tried with size 40, no change in behavior

Comment: `//using public IP, not local (127.0.0.1)` What do you mean when you mention different network? The address you use `192.168....` is not publicly routed. It is only visible within your local network. To be reachable via all interfaces you could use `INADDR_ANY` instead.

Comment: You state that opening the connection fails. But your code has a comment about an error only after the connection succeeded when you try to receive something. Did you verify whether the connection packages and also your hello message are sent using Wireshark etc.?

Comment: @Gerhardh My example with the 192.168... address is from trying to connect between two machines on my home wifi network. I used my public address when trying across networks.

Microsoft's description of the error that occurs on sending and receiving on the socket (10057) seems to suggest that the connection has already been lost by then. The connect() winsock function doesn't ever return an error value, even if I put in a meaningless address, so I don't really understand how to check for errors there. I will look into wireshark to confirm that data is actually being sent.

Comment: @JoshuaWhite "*The connect() winsock function doesn't ever return an error value, even if I put in a meaningless address*" - that is not possible for a TCP socket (you ARE using TCP, right? You did not show what `socket_setup()` looks like on both codes). `connect()` WILL report an error for TCP if you give it a bogus IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server needs to `bind()` to a local IP that belongs to the machine which the server is running on. Otherwise, you can `bind()` the server to `INADDR_ANY` (`0.0.0.0`) instead to bind to all local IPs on the machine.

The client can `connect()` to any IP that the server is bound to and listening on:

- If the client and server are running on the same machine, you can use any local IP, or `INADDR_LOOPBACK` (`127.0.0.1`).
- If the client and server are running on the same LAN network, you can `bind()` the server to the machine's LAN IP or `INADDR_ANY`, and then `connect()` the client to the server's LAN IP.
- If the client and server are running on different networks, the client must `connect()` to a public WAN IP that belongs to the server's network, AND the WAN/LAN router on that network must be configured with *port forwarding* enabled to pass incoming connections from a WAN IP/Port to the LAN IP/Port that the server is listening on.  Depending on the router's configuration, its port forwarding rules *MAY* be configurable dynamically directly from the server's code via the uPNP protocol, otherwise the rules will have to be configured manually by the network admin.

---

Now, that being said, something I do notice in your code - you say you are using *non-blocking* sockets.  That means `connect()` will fail with a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` (10035) error if the connection is *successfully* started in the background and in progress, however you are not waiting for that connection to actually finish being established before you then call `send()`/`recv()` on the socket.  That would account for the `WSAENOTCONN` (10057) error you are seeing.

You need to use `select()` or equivalent to make sure a non-blocking connection is fully established before you start exchanging data over it, eg:

```
if (connect(client_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&address, sizeof(address)) == 0) {
    printf("Connected\n");
}
else if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
    WSA_ERR("Connection Error");
}
else {
    fd_set wfds;
    FD_ZERO(&wfds);
    FD_SET(client_socket, &wfds);

    fd_set efds;
    FD_ZERO(&efds);
    FD_SET(client_socket, &efds);

    timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    int res = select(0, NULL, &wfds, &efds, &timeout);
    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        WSA_ERR("Select Error");
    }
    else if (res == 0) {
        WSASetLastError(WSAETIMEDOUT);
        WSA_ERR("Connection Error");
    }
    else if (FD_ISSET(client_socket, &efds)) {
        int err = 0;
        if (getsockopt(client_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &err)) == 0) {
            WSASetLastError(err);
        }
        WSA_ERR("Connection Error");
    }
    else {
        printf("Connected\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: "If the client and server are running on the same LAN network, bind the server to the machine's LAN IP or INADDR_ANY, and then connect() the client to the server's LAN IP"

I believe this is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: The machine running the server has "Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi address" 192.168.86.179. This is the address the server binds, and the address the client tries to connect to.

Comment: waiting on select() worked! thank you @RemyLebeau